# "Have a lot of people ask me" — Why causative here?

Tags: grammar, causatives, causative-have

As we all know, causatives are usually used to say that someone makes something for us. Then why is this sentence acceptable?

> *I have a lot of people ask me* whether it's possible to achieve their goals.

Is there an explanation? And what is the difference if I say:

> *A lot of people ask me* if it's possible [...]

Comment: "Have" is not causative in your example, but the stative use of "have" expressing 'experience'. A decent example of causative "have" is "Have your mechanics look at my car", where "have" means "arrange for". A stronger use of causative "have" is found in such examples as "They had Ed unlock the safe", where "have" means 'compel' or 'make'.

Answer (score 1):

> As we all know

I bet more than 95% of adults stopped on the street in native English-speaking countries would say *no* to the question "do you know about causatives in English grammar?".

> why causative here?

It's not a causative. Dictionary.com and wiktionary.org show 26 different definitions for the verb "have". There are many alternatives to the causative form of the word.

In this case:

> *To experience, go through, undergo:*
> We had a hard year last year, with the locust swarms and all that.
> He had surgery on his hip yesterday.
> I'm having the time of my life!

Also similar to this:

> *Used to state the existence or presence of someone in a specified relationship with the subject.*
> I have two sisters.
> She doesn't have any friends.
> I have a really mean boss.

And what is the difference if I say:

> A lot of people ask me if it's possible [...]

Approximately the same. No difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence simply means that

> I ***come across*** a lot of people ***who*** ask me whether it's possible to achieve their goals.

Or

> ***There are*** a lot of people ***who*** ask me whether it's possible to achieve their goals.

Or again

> ***My experience is that*** a lot of people ask me whether it's possible to achieve their goals.

This use of ***have*** may be quite common in practice, but it is definitely not causative.